# In which episode of Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D does Skye cry next to a trash bin?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, episode-identification, agents-of-shield

In which episode of Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D does Skye cry next to a trash bin?

Comment: What an oddly specific question...

Answer (score 8):

This occurs in [*The Only Light In The Darkness* (S01E19)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Only_Light_in_the_Darkness)

[image: skye cries]

The scene occurs after

> Skye has discovered Koenig's body and is on the run from Ward